# Is a bachelor or a widower person Godless according to the vedic scriptures?

Tags: scripture

According to this answer : [What is the real concept of brahmacharya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17156/what-is-the-real-concept-of-brahmacharya)

> **Wife is the supreme deity required to be worshipped by the husband .. In the body of the wife reside all the devatA-s. Likewise, the gArhapatyAgni which is verily brahmarUpa also resides in her body. Hence, she should be worshipped always by the husband. Thus declare the veda-s. Hence whosoever worships his wife & and gArhapatya, attains all one can aspire for in this world and is worshipped in brahmaloka after his death**.

So it seems from the answer that a bachelor or a widower is Godless.So is marriage just the way for worshipping the deities as per the vedas and a bachelor and a widower has no God?

I have never read in the biography of any saint that wife is the supreme God by the way.What I have read is 'stri-deva' (one to whom wife is the highest God) is a denigrating term according to the Purana-s.

But I am interested in knowing the truth.

Comment: "(one to whom wife is the highest God) is a denigrating term according to the Purana-s." - It is denigrating because it's referring to men who worship their wife for sex.

Comment: its truth aside, even going simply by the quoted section, it says 'Wife is the supreme deity required to be worshipped by the husband'.. it does not say 'woman is the supreme deity required to be worshiped by man' i.e. IF you marry, THEN do such & such. It does not say EVERYONE MUST marry and THEN do such & such.

Comment: @ram Thnx.But even if one marries, the SUPREME deities must be parents--isnt it? It seems that the slokas have little authenticity.

Comment: @Pratimaputra, that's why I said 'truth aside'. even if it were true, the answer to your question title is No.

Comment: @ram please write an answer

Comment: @Pratimaputra, then i have to find an online scripture to source what I learned from listening to upanyasa/pravachana, and i'm too lazy for that :)

Comment: You couod quote from any scripture providing the psloka and page no.There is no need to find out 'online' scripture @ram

Comment: @Pratimaputra actual meanings of MATHA PITHA GURU DEIVAM philosophy is different.  Its not related to parents who gave this body but parent of Atma. And that's secret which cannot be opened in public

Comment: @AkshayS There is Matridevo bhava.Pitridevo bhava '--in Upanishad

Comment: @AkshayS Manu also says that.

Comment: Of course parents have to be respected but the Matha Pitha philosphy meaning is entirely different! One who knows true meaning of it, door to Isvara opens!!!

Comment: @AkshayS What is that?

Comment: That's secret....cant open in public.