# Vow made before becoming hindu-must I follow it?

Tags: brahmacharya

I was born a christian and as a Christian/Catholic I made a vow of celibacy to Jesus.I am now hindu.must I follow this vow?would I go to hell for breaking this vow?

Comment: if you made a vow to Jesus, you could ask his advice before breaking it. (no i am not being sarcastic). also, similar vows exist in Hinduism also.

Comment: Breaking a vow is undoubtedly a sin and has its karmic consequences. I doubt, however, if breaking the vow of celibacy leads to hell.

Comment: In Hinduism too, celibacy must be maintained until you get married.

Comment: celibacy is not chastity.I said to jesus that id be celibate forever,as I wanted to become a catholic monk.it was a stupid idea and Ive broken the vow many times.I honestely dont want to follow it but if Shiva demands I do I will.

Comment: @johnyman In Hinduism, there is no concept of monk actually. After Brahmacharya, One must go into GrahstaAshrama which is getting married and having kids and doing all the duties for the family. Shiva himself is married to his Shakti(energy) in his sAkAra rupam.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17156/7853

Comment: The question like "would I go to hell for breaking the rules of a religion which I don't want to follow anymore?" makes no sense. One who decided to convert to a different religion should sever connections with his old beliefs and he should firmly establish himself in the believes of a religion he is converting to. If one is firm in a decision to sever with his old beliefs he should forget his old beliefs completely.

Answer (score -1):

You won't go to hell for breaking your vow, but yes there would be karmic consequences (as also mentioned in one of the comments) and you might not get liberation:

> *pādās trayo bahiś cāsann*
> *aprajānāṁ ya āśramāḥ*
> *antas tri-lokyās tv aparo*
> ***gṛha-medho ’bṛhad-vrataḥ***

> The spiritual world, which consists of three fourths of the Lord’s energy, is situated beyond this material world, and it is especially meant for those who will never be reborn. **Others, who are attached to family life and who do not strictly follow celibacy vows, must live within the three material worlds**.

So as the above verse from [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam 2.6.20](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/2/6/20/) states those who break vows especially the vow of celibacy remain in the material world.

Changing religions or faiths doesn't change the rules of a particular vow.

The reason you are asking seems that you have already broken vow, in that case beg for forgiveness from Jesus and also from the hindu deity you are trying to worship. Sincere apologies never go in vain. Even the Mahajan - Yamaraja begs for forgiveness ([Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam 6.6.30](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/6/3/30/)), so we should follow - *mahAjano yena gatAh sa panthAH*:

> *tat kṣamyatāṁ sa bhagavān puruṣaḥ purāṇo*
> *nārāyaṇaḥ sva-puruṣair yad asat kṛtaṁ naḥ*
> *svānām aho na viduṣāṁ racitāñjalīnāṁ*
> *kṣāntir garīyasi namaḥ puruṣāya bhūmne*

> O my Lord, my servants have surely committed a great offense by arresting a Vaiṣṇava such as Ajāmila. O Nārāyaṇa, O supreme and oldest person, please forgive us. Because of our ignorance, we failed to recognize Ajāmila as a servant of Your Lordship, and thus we have certainly committed a great offense. Therefore with folded hands we beg Your pardon. My Lord, since You are supremely merciful and are always full of good qualities, please pardon us. We offer our respectful obeisances unto You.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange! Please add references supporting your answer.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - He is a member since 2018 or even earlier. Still giving out a "Welcome to HSE" ? :-) :-)

Comment: @Carmensandiego haha There is a reason to that ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your kind comments :-D ... atleast during this lockdown somebody cares :-D