# What are the names of necessary Vratas after marriage?

Tags: marriage, vrata

Satyanarayana Vratam is popular among south Indians and people generally perform it after marriage. But I don't know whether it is necessary to conduct it after marriage or not.

Are there any necessary Vratas by scriptures that are needed to be performed after marriage?

Comment: [Brahmacharya vratam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/what-is-brahm-in-brahmacharya-how-does-it-relate-to-celibacy)

Comment: There are many.May be the question is falling in the category of too broad.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar what if I change from recommended to necessary?

Comment: I think the word essential or must should be there in order to separate the common vratas from mandatory ones.Or those are to be strictly followed after marriage. e.g. being honest to each other and to take care of each is also a vrata which a couple has to follow throughout their married life . so yes.

Comment: The vratas generally vary according to kulachara, lokachaara and deshachaara.I do not think any such vrata is followed throughout India.